# Max cpu usage big table

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-security, firebase-admin

I have a database with 1million users and I want to sort them according to their points. When I try to sort them, even if I use index it uses 100% of cpu and everything freezes for 1 minute. Should I use multiple databases to fix this problem ?

I don't want a query to use all processor single handedly?

my database rules.

```
   "userlist": {
      ".read": true,
      ".indexOn": ["coin", "fcb_coin","name","rateus","guestid","email"],
      "$uid": {
      ".write": "auth.uid==$uid",
      ".read": "true",


      }
    },
```

my database structure

```
  userlist: 
     uid:
        name:
        email:
        fcb_coin:
        device_type
        facebookid:
        deviceid:
```

my firebase cloud function

```
exports.createmyrankings = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {


  var db = admin.database().ref();

  db.child("userlist").orderByChild('fcb_coin').startAt(-999999999999).limitToFirst(50).once('value', (snapshot) => {

let mycount=1;
    snapshot.forEach((userSnap) => {

if(mycount<=50){
  snapshot.ref.parent.child('worldtop').child(mycount).remove();            
      snapshot.ref.parent.child('worldtop').child(mycount).child(userSnap.child('fcb_ids').val()).child('coin').set(userSnap.child('coin').val());  
      snapshot.ref.parent.child('worldtop').child(mycount).child(userSnap.child('fcb_ids').val()).child('name').set(userSnap.child('name').val()); 
          snapshot.ref.parent.child('worldtop').child(mycount).child(userSnap.child('fcb_ids').val()).child('fcb_ids').set(userSnap.child('fcb_ids').val()); 
mycount=mycount+1;
}


    });

  });





 response.send("ranking Is created");
 });
```

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference.Child("userlist").OrderByChild("coin").StartAt(-9999999999).EndAt(499)

its a simple code
using 100% of processor
i used index for coin value

My code works fine and I didn't said anything like "my code doesn't work". It's just that my code works slow because my table is big. As I stated, I need help with Firebase, not coding

Comment: You should probably show us your database structure with example content as well..Also, how you define the index in the FB rules.

Comment: Thanks for that additional info. The index looks good, so I wonder if it indeed takes that much time on the server to load the index. The alternative would most likely be related to data transfer. Can you do two more things for me? 1) Add `console.log(Date.now())` just before you call `once('value'` and then again right inside the callback before doing anything else. Then show the updated code and the logged output in the question. 2) Change the query to `.limitToFirst(1)` instead of `50`, run it again, and then show the logging results of that too.